# How to aggregate results from many rows into a single row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an Orders table, with OrderId as PK. I also have an Order_Products table with OrderId as FK. Each Order_Product row has columns like Product_Name, Product_Status,Product_Delivery_Date, etc. The tables are joined in one-to-many relationship on OrderId.

I am trying to design a query which will consolidate the two tables such that I get a row for each OrderId, but the query must have a Description column which will have the Oder_Name values of all Order_Product rows concatenated; I also need to have the aggregate Product_Status calculate using some logic like (if one of the products is 'NotCompleted', then the aggregate Product_Status will be 'NotCompleted'. Finally I would like to have the OrderDeliveryDate calculate such that it will be the MIN value of all Order_Product Product_Delivery_Date values.

I am using MySql. Can you please give me some advice as to how to achieve these three tasks?

Example:

### Orders Table:

OrderId  CustomerName

1001     CustomerX

### OrderProducts Table:

Id  OrderId  ProductDescription  ProductDeliveryDate   ProductStatus
20  1001     ProductA                        2015-01-30            NotCompleted
21  1001     ProductB            2015-01-15            Completed
24  1001     ProductC            2015-02-13            NotCompleted

### Desired Query Output:

OrderId    CustomerName   Description                  OrderDeliveryDate     OrderStatus
'1001'    'CustomerX'     'ProductA,ProductB,ProductC' '2015-01-15'          'NotCompleted'

Comment: You should edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, a query such a the following may do what you want:

```
select o.*, op.status, op.orderdeliverydate, op.description
from orders o join
     (select OrderId, group_concat(op.order_name) as description,
             (case when sum(Product_Status = 'Not Completed') > 0 then 'Not Completed'
                   else 'Completed'
              end) as Status,
             min(Product_Delivery_date) as OrderDeliveryDate
      from Order_Product
      group by OrderId
     ) op
     on o.OrderId = p.OrderId;
```

Comment: thanks for your response; it seems to be solving two out of three of my problems; any ideas on how to tackle the description issue?

Comment: @user1012598 . . . That would appear to require `group_concat()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Please see an example of the requirement above.